# Spring cloud stream rabbitmq performance testing

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I have set up a spring cloud stream with rabbitmq binder. I want to do performance testing with the spring cloud stream. is there any way to do performance testing with that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use any available performance tools as you would with an other Java application.
Do you have some SLA that you are trying to target or you just want to compare it to some other approach? Do you know message sizes, network/hardware infrastructure, bandwidth etc.?

All I am trying to say is that "performance" testing only makes sense if you know your targets, otherwise what is fast/slow?

Comment: I want to do the same with different broker binders like Artemis, Kafka, SQL, and AWS Kinesis with the same approach. Based on performance I want to select a broker

Comment: You don't need Spring Cloud Stream or Spring in general to do what you're describing. Also, if you google, you can probably find performance characteristics and comparison of individual brokers. That said, you seem to want to compare 'apples' and 'oranges' which I am not sure how you're going to accomplish that. For example how can you compare Kafka and SQL as they are completely unrelated. Event Kafka to RabbitMQ or any JMS broker.. . . The architecture of certain brokers are made for specific types of use cases while your seem to want to treat them as general purpose message brokers...

Comment: I have data in my DB i.e master data which will be picked by publisher application and sent to the consumer via the broker. So I want to test which broker will give the best performance-based data that the broker can process with some other features like a cluster that's my requirement.